# laravel Set a time interval for sending verification code as SMS to activate the user after registration

Tags: php, laravel

how can I set time interval or time difference between the first time the user requested for the verification code and the second try which should be 30 seconds?
also how to display the time counter: 29:00 down to 0 seconds?

```
public function sendSms($request)
{

$apiKey = config('services.smsapi.ApiKey'); 
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();   
$endpoint = "https://www.sms123.net/api/send.php";    

try
{
$response = $client->request('GET', $endpoint, ['query' => [
    'recipients' => $request->contact_number, 
    'apiKey' => $apiKey,
    'messageContent'=>'testSite.com verification code is '.$request->code,
]]);

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$content = $response->getBody();
$content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
return $content['msgCode'];

 }
  catch (Exception $e)
     {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Thankfully, Laravel gets you covered in this aspect. In Laravel, you can achieve rate-limiting using a middleware called `throttle` which comes out of the box in Laravel. You need to assign this `throttle` middleware to the route or group of routes.

The middleware basically accepts two parameters, specifically “number of requests” and “duration of time”, which determines the maximum number of requests that can be made in a given number of minutes.

**Basic example**

You can assign a `throttle` middleware to a single route like below

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth', 'throttle:30,1');
```

As you can see, the above route configuration will allow an authenticated user access route 30 times per minute. If user exceed this limit within the specified time span, Laravel will return a `429 Too Many Requests` with following response headers.

```
x-ratelimit-limit: 2
x-ratelimit-remaining: 0
x-ratelimit-reset: 1566834663
```

Then with vue or js on your frontend you can make a counter that will start counting the desired number so that the user knows how much time he has left.